# Getting a Ruby on Rails 4 model to accept an uploaded file as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm relatively new to Rails 4.  I thought was getting the hang of the params.require method in the controller of a model that dictates what parameters it will take, but right now I'm totally stumped.

It's a Ruby on Rails web application in which I need to have one model - a 'contact' have many uploaded files.  I'm calling my uploaded file model a 'related_document.'

My Contact model includes the following:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :related_documents, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

My RelatedDocuments model includes this:

```
class RelatedDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact          
  has_attached_file :document  

  validates_attachment_presence :document
end
```

My RelatedDocumentsController includes the following:

```
def related_document_params
  params.require(:related_document).permit(:contact_id, :document_file_name, :document_content_type, :document_file_size, :document_updated_at)
end
```

My Contacts Controller calls the following function when it uploads a file.  When it does, params[:related_document] consists of exactly two parameters:  'contact_id' - which is the id of the contact it belongs to; and 'document' - which is an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError which is an ActionDisplatch::http:UploadedFile object.

```
def file_upload
    @related_doc = RelatedDocument.new(params[:related_document])
end
```

This is where it barfs - it gives me an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError.  I don't understand why - since I'm including both the contact_id and the document in the params.require of the RelatedDocumentsController.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Try `@related_doc = RelatedDocument.new(related_document_params)` I'm a novice too, but I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not allowed the document attribute. Try this:

```
def related_document_params
  params.require(:related_document).permit(:contact_id, :document_file_name, :document_content_type, :document_file_size, :document_updated_at, :document)
end
```

Notice the `:document` at the end of the permitted params.